# Kotlin multiplatform : integrates cocoapods refering to a hosted git repository?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

I've integrated cocoapods for a kotlin multiplatform library as described in the kotlinlang reference : [CocoaPods integration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/cocoapods.html).

Long story short, to use my multiplatform lib in the iOS project I need to clone the library which has a podspec. I open the lib with Android Studio so the IDE configures the android sdk local path. Then I add a reference to the lib in the podfile of my iOS project.
The podfile of my iOS project looks like this:

```
target 'my-ios-app' do
     pod 'my_kotlin_library', :path => 'path/to/my-kotlin-library'
 end
```

**What I expect** is to refer directly to an online git repository in the podfile:

```
target 'my-ios-app' do
     pod 'my_kotlin_library', :path => 'url to an online git repo'
 end
```

The main obstacle I see is that Xcode needs the Android sdk local path when compiling the project. Is there any way to achieve what I expect?

Comment: Can you change `:path` to the `:git` reference?

Comment: No, as I described, Xcode needs the Android sdk local path when compiling the project.